# Simplify algebra exponent

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know I have asked a similar question in the past I am stuck on this question.

How would I simplify the following:

$$\left(\frac{xy^{-4}}{2^{-1}x^{-2}}\right)^3\left(\frac{8x^{-2}y^0}{3^{-1}xy^{-3}}\right)^{-2}$$

I have done

$$\frac{x^3y^{-12}}{2^{-3}x^{-6}}\left(\frac{3^{-1}xy^{-3}}{8x^{-2}\cdot 1}\right)^2$$

$$\frac{x^9y^{-12}}{2^{-3}}\frac{3^{-2}x^2y^{-6}}{64x^{-4}}$$

Unfortunately I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: You can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/464/264) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/161783). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful. If you need to format more advanced things, there are many excellent references on LaTeX on the internet, including StackExchange's own [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: @ZevChonoles I wish there was a way to +1 an edit.  That was awesome, but also a lot of work.  Thanks for clearing up the question!

Comment: @anorton: Thanks for your kind words :) I don't want questions to be discriminated against due to poor formatting, and I can write LaTeX pretty quick, so I like to help when I can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{x^9y^{-12}}{2^{-3}}\frac{3^{-2}x^2y^{-6}}{64x^{-4}}$$
Remember that $a^{-n} = \frac{1}{a^n}$.
Thus, we have:
$$\frac{2^3x^9}{y^{12}}\cdot\frac{x^2x^4}{64\cdot3^2y^6}$$
At this point, we have $a^na^m=a^{n+m}$.  I've also changed $64=2^6$.
$$\frac{2^3x^{15}}{2^6\cdot3^2y^{18}}$$
Note that we can cancel some of the twos:
$$\frac{x^{15}}{2^3\cdot3^2y^{18}}$$
These numbers are easier to work with:
$$\frac{x^{15}}{8\cdot9y^{18}}$$
$$\frac{x^{15}}{72y^{18}}$$
Done. :-)

Please let me know if you have any questions.  A reminder--please accept the answer that you feel best answers your question (if, in your opinion, one does).  This will encourage people to answer your future questions.

Comment: muchas gracias senor.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing well so far! Now you just need to combine the two fractions together, using the rule
$$\frac{a}{b}\times\frac{c}{d}=\frac{ac}{bd}$$
Thus, you'll get
$$\frac{x^9y^{-12}3^{-2}x^2y^{-6}}{2^{-3}64x^{-4}}$$
I think all the remaining steps after this are ones you've demonstrated knowledge of already, though if you need further help I can add more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the next step would be to get rid of the negative exponents $$\frac{8x^9}{y^{12}}\frac{x^6}{(9)(64)y^6}$$ Now you just simplify by multiplying and reducing the coefficients $$\frac{x^{15}}{72y^{18}}$$ Hope this helps.